# Ripple Effect Needs to Have Container View?

Tags: android, android-layout

For a number of reasons, I need to provide a custom `ImageButton` in my app for the up button. I have a simple layout in my app, which includes the following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/up_container"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

        <ImageButton
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:id="@+id/action_up"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/up"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I noticed that I wasn't getting the ripple effect on the `ImageButton` unless I placed it into another `FrameLayout`, which is the `up_container`.

My question is: Why is this additional `FrameLayout` necessary to have the ripple effect? It seems redundant. If I took out `up_container` and made the up button a direct child of my root `FrameLayout`, then the ripple effect would not occur.

Any ideas on this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: did you try `?attr` `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: I have that in my code. It's shown in the code snippet in the original question. Even with that attribute set in that way, if I remove the `up_container`, the ripple effect does not occur.